# jQuery in Google's Accelerated Mobile Pages

Tags: jquery, accelerated-mobile-page

Can I use jQuery in Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMPs) by creating amp-jQuery Component / Tag?

Am I limited only to use available [Components / Tag](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components)?

If I can create custom Components/Tags, how can i create one?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't use any custom javascript on AMP pages.
I am assuming you want some of your component to be interactive which is not yet provided by amp-component.
You can choose to use amp-iframe, host a a url containing that jquery enabled component.